# Задачу решил самостоятельно, но после просмотра других решений, понимаю что мой код избыточен

Tags: java, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

```
  public static long[] productFib(long prod) {
    // your code
    ArrayList<Long> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    fib(46,arrayList);
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size()-1; i++) {
        list.add(arrayList.get(i)*arrayList.get(i+1));
    }
    TreeMap<Long,String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        map.put(list.get(i),arrayList.get(i)+" "+arrayList.get(i+1));
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(46));
    if (map.containsKey(prod)){
        String[] strings = map.get(prod).split(" ");
        return new long[]{Long.parseLong(strings[0]),Long.parseLong(strings[1]),1};
    }
    if (!map.containsKey(prod)){
        Long key = map.keySet().stream().filter(aLong -> aLong >= prod).min(Long::compareTo).get();
        String[] strings = map.get(key).split(" ");
        return new long[]{Long.parseLong(strings[0]),Long.parseLong(strings[1]),0};

    }

    return null;
}
static  void fib(int n, List<Long> list) {
    long start = 0;
    long next = 1;
    long result = 0;
    list.add(result);
    list.add(next);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result = start + next;
        start = next;
        next = result;
        list.add(result);
    }

}
```

}

[Это таск с кодварс](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5541f58a944b85ce6d00006a)

Нужны советы, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Первое, что вы делаете не так - оформляете таким образом вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

У вас что-то из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно".

Я Java не знаю, так что явно можно изобразить и красивее, но для укладывающихся в `long` чисел получается очень просто:

```
public static long[] productFib(long prod)
{
    long a = 0, b = 1;
    while(a*b < prod)
    {
        b = b + a;
        a = b - a;
    }
    long[] z = {a, b, (a*b==prod) ? 1 : 0};
    return z;
}
```

Просто считаем очередную пару и все.

Программа — [тут](https://ideone.com/Hw1TGd).

Comment: `int` -> `long`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Охотно поверю :) — я просто потыкался на ideone, заработало — и ладно... Ну не мультилингва я :)

Comment: Я глянул на задание. Там `long` в интерфейсе. Только потому и написал.